# target 'Amplitude' has invalid header layout: umbrella header found at

Tags: swift, xcode12.5

When I integrate a local package in my Xcode project everything is fine initially but when i switch branches and want to run the app Xcode gives me the compile error Missing package product .

We also integrate external packages via Swift Package Manager which works perfectly fine. No issues there.
Showing Recent Messages
target 'Amplitude' has invalid header layout: umbrella header found at '/Users/tellez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eal-clddabmvdnoywidszrxurahnalhc/SourcePackages/checkouts/Amplitude-iOS/Sources/Amplitude/Amplitude.h', but directories exist next to it: /Users/tellez/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/eal-clddabmvdnoywidszrxurahnalhc/SourcePackages/checkouts/Amplitude-iOS/Sources/Amplitude/Resources; consider removing them

1:  File > Swift Packages > Reset Package Caches  - NO WORKS

2: File > Swift Packages > Update to Latest Package Versions - NO WORKS

3: In Xcode go to Product > Clean Build Folder - NO WORKS

Comment: Please show your current code or what is needed to reproduce

Comment: @aheze I'm getting the same thing simply trying to use [TZImagePickerController](https://github.com/banchichen/TZImagePickerController) in a new, empty project

Comment: @BenLeggiero there seems to be a issue opened in the repo --> https://github.com/banchichen/TZImagePickerController/issues/1496

Comment: I found only one thing how resolved this problem, delete all Swift Package and add all this again

Comment: I also solved this problem by removing 'Amplitude' from SPM and then re-adding 'Amplitude' from SPM.

But there were some errors in other packages, so, I had to delete all packages and then re-added all packages and build errors were fixed.